# In Javascript, what is {% include file.js %}?

Tags: javascript

I'm mucking with some HTML files that have lines like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {% include parameters480p.js %}  // huh?
    // more javascript...
</script>
```

I don't recognize the syntax for that include line. Neither does my browser. Can someone clue me in? Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't come from pure javascript but from some framework, which probably detects that part and replaces it accordingly.

Comment: Seems like that file is processed by sone server side template library.

Comment: *"In Javascript, what is {% include file.js %}?"* A syntax error :P

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I would throw this out there as a possible answer. I performed a search on symbol hound and it looks like it is used in Django templates. You can see the search results here: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%7B%25+include

If it is django, here is documentation about `include` from the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include

> ### include
>
> Loads a template and renders it with the current context. This is a
>   way of “including” other templates within a template.
>
> The template name can either be a variable or a hard-coded (quoted)
>   string, in either single or double quotes.
>
> This example includes the contents of the template "foo/bar.html":
>
> ```
> {% include "foo/bar.html" %}
> ```

Comment: Depending on the server-side language, it could also be any project using [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) (for PHP), or [nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include) (JavaScript), amongst others. A lot of tempting languages have copied Django template syntax.

Comment: Thanks all! Now I've learned of both symbol hound and django. (I think I'll just convert these to regular javascript rather than learn a new tech layer... it's a small project.)

Answer (score 1):

Likely used by a server side language or templating engine/pre-processor of some kind - it's not "normal" HTML/JS

Comment: Unless you know which server-side language, this doesn't help much.

Comment: Usually would have clarified with a specific technology but couldn't determine which it was via a quick search. Knowing where the HTML files came from or what other files were associated with it (does it have a dependencies file or build script that can be inspected to determine what's pre-processing it).